# How to accept last draggable and revert the previous one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an exercice where I have to drag words into gaps.

HTML :

```
<div>
<ul class="boxy">
    <li id="box0" class="dragli">box0</li>
    <li id="box1" class="dragli">box1</li>
    <li id="box2" class="dragli">box2</li>
</ul>
<br /><br />
</div>

<div>
<br />
    gap0 :
    <span class="GapSpan" id="GapSpan0">
    <input type="text" id="Gap0"  class="GapBox" size="7"></input>  
    </span>
    gap1 :
    <span class="GapSpan" id="GapSpan1">
    <input type="text" id="Gap1"  class="GapBox" size="7"></input>  
    </span>
    gap2 :
    <span class="GapSpan" id="GapSpan2">
    <input type="text" id="Gap2" class="GapBox" size="7"></input>
   </span>
</div>
```

If I drop a word in a gap where a word has been previously dropped, I'd like to see this previous word coming back to its original place and being replaced by the new one.

I'm not at all confortable with jquery and tried different solutions without any success.
Here's where I am :

```
GAPS =new Array();
for (var g=0; g<3; g++)// gapnum
{
    GAPS[g] = new Array(); 
    GAPS[g][0] = -1;//boxnum or -1
}

$( init );  
function init() {

$(".dragli").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    scroll: true,       
    revert: false,
    helper : 'clone',
    start: function (event, ui) {
           ui.helper.data('previous-position', ui.helper.offset());
      },

});

$(".GapBox").droppable({

    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var gapnum = $(this).attr('id').substring(3);
        var boxnum = ui.draggable.attr('id').substring(3);
        //If there is a word prior to the current one on this gap
        if (GAPS[parseInt(gapnum)][0] != -1) //yes
        {
            var previous_idbox= 'box'+GAPS[parseInt(gapnum)][0];// previous word
            //go home !
            // next line is not working
            //$("#" + previous_idbox).animate($("#" + previous_idbox).data().originalLocation, "slow");
        }
        else {
            GAPS[parseInt(gapnum)][0] =boxnum;  // storage
        }
        ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'center', at: 'center' } );
    },

});
```

}

I'm sure there is a better way than using an array for storage, to know which draggable is in the droppable but I don't know how to do that.

And I don't know how to revert the previous word back home.

Could you help me ?

You can see the file [here](http://lpae002.free.fr//hack_hotpot/tests/test_jquery_accept_last_item_3.htm)

---

I managed to do what I wanted greatly inspired by the Raymond Macaalay's script (see the link in my comment to Faron's answer).
Here's the script :

```
$(function () {
var previous_boxId = "";

$(".dragli").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    scroll: true,       
    revert: false,
    helper : 'clone',
    start: function (event, ui) {
           Positioning.initialize($(this));
      },

});

$(".GapBox").droppable({

    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var gapId = $(this).attr('id');
        var boxId = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
        // drop the current draggable
        ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'center', at: 'center' } );
        //If there is a word prior to the current one on this gap
        if ( (previous_boxId != "") && ($("#" + previous_boxId).data("gap_id") == gapId) )
        {
            //go home !
            $("#" + previous_boxId).animate($("#" + previous_boxId).data().originalLocation, "slow");

        }

            previous_boxId = boxId;
                $("#" + previous_boxId).data("gap_id", gapId);

    },

    out: function (event, ui) {
            var boxId = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
            $(ui.draggable).animate($(ui.draggable).data().previous-position, "slow");
        },

});

});

var Positioning = (function () {
    return {
        //Initializes the starting coordinates of the object
        initialize: function (object) {
            object.data("originalLocation", $(this).originalPosition = { top: 0, left: 0 });
            object.data("previous-position", $(this).offset());
        },
        //Resets the object to its starting coordinates
        reset: function (object) {
            object.data("originalLocation").originalPosition = { top: 0, left: 0 };
        },
    };
})();
```

The result can be seen [here](http://lpae002.free.fr//hack_hotpot/tests/test_jquery_accept_last_item_8.htm).

Comment: I meant no offense however, it does take a bit time to get used with jQuery - but, it does the job well and it has many wrapped global functions where you could write less but with more function (animation, etc).  If I were you, I'd keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment - I went ahead and whipped you a script to show what I meant by my comment.

This is totally different approach on how to script it but it produce the result as what you are looking, if I am correct in understanding your concept.  What I did was attaching jQuery UI to the DOM along with jQuery and this is the script.

```
$(function() {
$( "#context" ).draggable();
var getcontent = $('#text').text();
$( "#transfer" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( getcontent );
      $('#text').empty();
  }
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="context" >
<p id="text">my variable string</p>
</div>

<div id="transfer">
<p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #context{ width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
 #transfer{ width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
```

Here's [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/K9FNh/2/) for this.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late answer but Morpheus got me in his arms. I'd like to stay with my approach because this is only a part of a big project and I don't want to rewrite it.
I found a Raymond Macaalay's script which could help me [link](http://macaalay.com/2013/11/15/accept-only-the-latest-dropped-draggable-in-a-droppable-interaction-using-jquery-ui/). I'm working on that base.

Comment: Totally understood.  See this as an "FYI" for back of your head for future development.  ;)